# Is there any way to use Google Analytics on WordPress without plugin or the ability to edit the header?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I am making the website using the theme of a university, while I don't have the ability to use plugins and edit the head.php or function.php doc, which are the main method I can find to use Google Analytics on WordPress. I tried to add the code of Google Analytics to other places on our WordPress website, but it doesn't work.
Is there anybody who could help me about this? Thank you very much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Why** can't you install plugins or change theme files? So how do you implement the website?

there are many plugins you can use in [**wordpress plugin repository**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).

You can also achieve the goal by editing the functions.php file of your **active theme** and adding the following code at the end of file.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_google_analytics');
function my_google_analytics() { ?>    
?>
    <script>
        // Paste your Google Analytics tracking code script here.
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The website was provided by the university so that I can only use the default theme and cannot change theme files. Is there any way to add the code directly into the body content of the website?

Comment: @Jiangong Do you have access to the default theme code? or can you create a child-theme and upload it to server?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Google Analytics snippet in an article
through an **Custom HTML** element in widget category (i tried and it works).

Note: for an optimized tracking it is important that the Google Analytics snippet, in addition to the article pages, is also present on all the other pages of the site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why did it show that "Tag <script> is not allowed" when I tried to add custom HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Add a footer widget (since it renders on all pages).
Choose type "Custom Text/HTML"
Enter the following content:

```
<script>
<!-- YOUR GOOGLE ANALYTICS JAVASCRIPT --!>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it showed that "Target <script> is not allowed" when I tried to add "Custom HTML" widget.

Answer (score 0):

I've readed that "Custom HTML" element doesn't work in your pages. Have you tried put a Custom HTML in Widgets? It could work a bit different.

It's very common to put the Analytics code... Ask to the university tech support. The should have other experiencies about that.